# What's the best way to set up the AAD directory as a data source for Language Studio?

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-ai

Been managing a helpdesk for the past 5 years at the same client and I'm keen to start leveraging the whole hype around AI to get the client to start using a bot for simple QnA's or for the techs to use as a shortcut to manage group permissions.

Just finished my AI900, and I've been playing around with the Language studio. I'm trying to find a way to connect a Language Service with AAD, in order for it to pull information from users within the directory as a start.

Did some research and I'm just confused as to what needs to be done.

On one end, I'm able to create a language service with custom question answering that uses a Search service to pull data from and create a new App Registration with the appropriate Graph API permissions, but I'm not finding a way to set this up as a source. Do I need to set up a SQL database between that and the Language Service (Cosmos DB or something similar) in order for it to work?

On the other end, Microsoft is pushing Virtual Power Agents as they have an AI Builder, but it's almost cost prohibitive at this stage. Tried using AI Builder on the Azure instance I set up for the AI900 but I'm being served a "Need a Premium Account to use this", even though I've set up trials for all the licenses required, with the exception of Dataverse which I'm not being allowed to create a resource (?).

Any ideas are much appreciated!